# Converting numpy ndarray of dictionaries to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've searched stackoverflow for a solution to this -> but all solutions are slightly different to my needs.

I have a large ndarray (roughly 107 million rows) lets call it `df`:

```
    [{'A': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 3},
     {'A': 7, 'B': 9, 'F': 5},
     {'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'E': 6}]
```

I need it to be converted to a DataFrame as time efficiently as possible. This is an example desired output:

```
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  5.0  NaN  3.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
1  7.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
2  NaN  4.0  7.0  NaN  6.0  NaN
```

I have tried `pd.DataFrame(df)` and `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)` but these give me the output:

```
     0
0  {'A': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 3}
1  {'A': 7, 'B': 9, 'F': 5}
2  {'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'E': 6}
```

The question: How do I convert `df` to the desired output?

EDIT:

I have tried  anky_91's solution. This will work for a list - NOT an ndarray. I want to avoid converting to a list as having 107million values in a list causes memory errors.

```
pd.DataFrame(df).sort_index(axis=1)
```

This still gives me the same output as pd.DataFrame(df). It outputs a DataFrame containing one column with dictionary in each row.

Comment: i dont get the question: `pd.DataFrame(a).sort_index(axis=1)` works fine and matches the expected output

Comment: `pd.DataFrame([d for d in arr])`

Comment: Tested solution from anky_91 - works exactly as needed. Very elegant!

Comment: @anky_91see edit under 'EDIT' section of the question. I am still receiving the same output as running `pd.DataFrame(df)`. df is of type ndarray.

Comment: If `df` (what an odd name) is an `ndarray` then `pd.DataFrame(df)` won't work. You can convert it to list: `pd.DataFrame(df.tolist())`. Haven't testing the performance though. pandas with 100M rows can usually bring down any personal computer

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but why would anyone want to create an array of dictionaries?

Comment: @Mstaino A function from a library I am using returns a dictionary - To improve the performance of calling the function on 107 million rows I am using `np.vectorize` on the function. Calling the vectorized function returns an array of the original return value. So I'm stuck with an numpy array of dicts :(

Comment: `np.vectorize` is just an elegant wrapper for a `for` loop, it does not improve performance

Comment: I see two solutions: one is creating a numpy array with a nicer structure by modifying the function, second is using Code_Different's solution and splitting the task in chunks to prevent the machine from crashing, then appending the dataframes

Comment: @Mstaino would you recommend scrapping the `np.vectorize` and creating my own vectorizing function that returns a dataframe? - I am already splitting the task into chunks, it's just not show in the question as I didn't think it was required at the time.

Comment: A object dtype array already uses dictionary references.  `tolist` shouldn't  change memory use that much.

Comment: @RMRiver yes, I think it would be better. If you want named columns as in a dictionary you can also try to create a structured array and use `pd.DataFrame.from_records`

Answer (score 1):

I think input data are different:

```
L =  [[{'A': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 3}],
     [{'A': 7, 'B': 9, 'F': 5}],
     [{'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'E': 6}]]

print (pd.DataFrame(L))
                          0
0  {'A': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 3}
1  {'A': 7, 'B': 9, 'F': 5}
2  {'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'E': 6}
```

Possible solution is flattening:

```
from  itertools import chain
df = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(L)).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  5.0  NaN  3.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
1  7.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
2  NaN  4.0  7.0  NaN  6.0  NaN
```

If input datais numpy array use solution from comment by @Code Different:

```
arr = np.array([{'A': 5, 'C': 3, 'D': 3},
                {'A': 7, 'B': 9, 'F': 5},
                {'B': 4, 'C': 7, 'E': 6}])

df = pd.DataFrame(arr.tolist()).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
     A    B    C    D    E    F
0  5.0  NaN  3.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
1  7.0  9.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0
2  NaN  4.0  7.0  NaN  6.0  NaN
```

Comment: In this solution output columns are not sorted, unlike in the one from anky_91 above.